# Date conversion from 29/08/2013 to milliseconds

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, date

I did test several simple date format convertion, like the one bellow and similar other:

```
var toParse:String = "Thu Aug 29 2013";
var milliseconds:Number = Date.parse(toParse);
```

I'd like to know if there exist something as simple as this method to convert the format 29/08/2013 to milliseconds.

Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works the same with `29/08/2013` although the `Date.parse` just takes it as `mm/dd/yyyy`. So you need to do:

```
var toParse:String = "08/29/2013";
var milliseconds:Number = Date.parse(toParse);
```

Comment: It must be mm/dd/yyyy or it can be m/d/yyyy? (08/29/2013 = 8/29/2013)

Comment: Yeah you can also do `8/29/2013`.